# How to see files in a particular commit in git?

Tags: git

I want to see all the files that were committed in a particular commit in git, how do I do that?

Comment: if you are on linux, you can use `gitk` to view such info on gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git show --pretty="format:" --name-only <commit_id>`. This will list all the files that were committed in a particular commit.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways to do this

**Method 1:** `git show --name-only {commit}`

Example - `git show --name-only a303aa90779efdd2f6b9d90693e2cbbbe4613c1d`

**Method 2:** Method 1 will give you a lot of additional diff information and in case you are only interested in looking at ONLY the files that were changedthen you can use this-

Example `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r fv42bi45`

**Method 3:** You can also use this as an alternate to Method 2.
Example `git show --pretty="format:" --name-only fv42bi45`